# Drush hangs when started from subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, linux, bash

I am trying to pass a pretty long bash command into my Popen command.  The command is this -

`'/usr/local/bin/drush --alias-path=/data/scripts/drush_aliases @test pml -y | /bin/grep -i dblog | /bin/grep -i enabled'`

When passing the whole command in one go, the Popen command doesn't return the correct output in Cron.  In order to remedy this, I am trying to split it apart into a list (as seen in "command") as pass it in in order to get around the issue.

In my full code, I'm chaining together several different `Popen` objects. However, my bug can be reproduced with only the following:

```
command = ['/usr/local/bin/drush', '--alias-path=/data/scripts/drush_aliases', '@test', 'pml', '-y']

try:
   process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   output = process.communicate()
```

What can cause this hang?

Comment: What line of your file do you get this error on?

Comment: your code is OK. this error occurs if `/usr/local/bin/drush` cannot be found. Can you try to simplify your command by changing to `ls` ?

Comment: The error appears at the subprocess.Popen command.  When changing to command to ls it works fine.  If I change the command to just /usr/local/bin/drush it also works correctly.  It only fails when I add the necessary arguments/parameters to it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your full command, the one at the top of the question, uses pipelines.  Pipelines are a shell feature and will not work unless Popen is given the `shell=True` option.  (The alternative is to make your own pipeline by piecing together multiple Popen commands.)

Comment: I took out the shell=True option until I got the first part of the commands with drush working correctly.  Once I get that part working I'll chain the Popen commands together.  I'll add that commented code back in.

Comment: If it helps, the same command with the variable works correctly if I use subprocess.call(command).  It just doesn't work for Popen for some reason.

Comment: can you [edit] your question to show which `subprocess.call` code works? that's becoming interesting :)

Comment: note that since you have the output, you should consider processing the text in python and not with `grep`

Comment: I added the commands and their successes/failures,  Is there a way to check the output when using subprocess.call?   My version of Python does not support the `subprocess.check_output` command.

Comment: `command = ['/usr/local/bin/drush --alias-path=/data/scripts/drush_aliases @test pml', '-y']` can be expected to fail. There's no file named `drush --alias-path=...`, and it's looking for such a file because you aren't splitting the command name and its arguments into separate array elements. There's nothing interesting/surprising/unusual about that failure.

Comment: ...now, as for the hang -- I wonder if it's trying to read from your Python process's stdin. If you set `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`, does behavior change?

Comment: !  Looks like it works now after setting stdin.  Thanks so much.  If you want to go ahead and add that as an aswer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most common reasons for a process to hang is if it's trying to read input from stdin.

You can work around this by explicitly passing a closed pipe (or a handle on `/dev/null`) on stdin:

```
   process = subprocess.Popen(command,
       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
       stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
       stdin=subprocess.PIPE)  ## this is new
```

`communicate()` will close the pipe passed to stdin after writing any content passed to it as an argument, preventing the process from hanging.

In Python 3.2 or newer, you can also use `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL`.